# Interrupting a Variable With Content Then continue

Tags: php

What I was curious to know is if there is a way to include a variable within the output of $article_content . Specifically I'm trying to output after the first instance of `<p></p>` or first paragraph. Interrupting the rest of my variable with a quick insert then continuing that variable

The reason I'm doing this is I've added old content to a database to make my life easier. I had google(ad) code within that(after the first paragraph) which no longer works coming from the database. It is something that will have to be added after as that output doesn't work. Is there a way to do this? I did this before for example by just doing this.

```
<h1>The Page Title</h1>
<p>Some content goes here</p>
<div>Goog script</div>
<p>Content continues here</p>
```

As I write this I'm imagining a variable that begins then finishes later in the page like so

```
$variable .= 'First Part of content = Some content goes here';
$variable .= 'First Part of content = Some content goes here';

<?php echo $variable; ?>
<div>Goog script</div>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

Of course $variable begins then variable ends using the same $article_content  variable.

Please let me know if this is confusing

```
<?php
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Connect to the MySQL database
include "newInclude/db_conx.php";
$id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); // filter everything but numbers
// Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product

$sqlCommand = "UPDATE articles SET views=views+1 WHERE ID=$id";
// Execute the query here now
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlCommand);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$sqlcount = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
$sql_count = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqlcount);
$blogCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql_count); 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($blogCount > 0) {
// get all the product details
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_count)){
$article_title = $row["article_title"];
$category = $row["category"];
$readmore = $row["readmore"];
$author = $row["author"];
$date_added = $row["date_added"];
$article_content = $row["content"];
}

} else {
echo "That item does not exist.";
exit();
}

} else {
echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
exit();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>
```

Is this what you're referring to @gabe?

```
<?php echo $beginning_text . <script type="text/javascript"></script> . $the_rest; ?>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you want to insert something in the middle of your "content", which is something that you retrieve from a table field. Is that it? If not, please update your question to make it clearer.

Comment: If your google ad code is part of the old $atricle_content in the DB you could try a simple str_replace on $article_content. The no longer working code would be the first arg, the new ad code would be the second arg, and the third arg would be $article_content. That way $article_content would display just as it does now except the old, not working, ad would be replaced by the new ad.

Comment: Right, article_content displays fine. I just want to add "content(ad ec.t)" in between the content. That's confusing I know, but I can't think of any other way to explain this. What goes in the middle of the content will not be coming from the database. It can be a defined variable on the page itself. In fact that is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to grab the content from the database as I normally would while inserting the "content(ad ect.)" in between.

Comment: @gabe to not go off on a tangent here let's assume I just have a variable which I defined as $variable = 'In between content'; rather than any google code.

Comment: My thought wasn't specific to Google ad code. And recognizable string contained within $article_content would accomplish the task just fine. You said you had ad code coming from the DB. The question is really, how does it work now vs how do you want it to work. If you like the current display of the content then do a simple str_replace as described above where you swap the old code for the new code. If you want to display the content differently than you do now then it gets a little trickier but not hard.

Comment: Assuming you always want it after the first </p> you could use `$beginning_pos = strpos($article_content, "</p>");` then `$beginning_text = substr($article_content, 0, $beginning_pos);` then `$the_rest = substr($articl_content, $beginning_pos + 1);` then your output is `echo $beginning_text . <your ad code> . $the_rest;`

Comment: That is an interesting thought...I 'm getting an error when I try to implement this. I'm updating the Original Post @gabe . Let me know if this is what you're referring to.

Comment: I got it @gabe . That's exactly what I'm trying to do. If you can create your response as an answer I can accept ect. One thing that I'm noticing is that it's leaving /p> at the end of the output. Any idea why that may be occuring?

Comment: I fixed the \p> part showing up in the answer below. We are searching for a string of 4 characters. The strpos function returns the position of the first char in the string. In the comment above, I have $the_rest starting only 1 char after the beginning of <\p> so $the_rest starts with \p>. I'm guessing that is why (in a web browser) you are seeing a \p> on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your article content needs to be broken up into 2 pieces and have some code inserted in between the 2 pieces. According to your question you always want it at the end of the first paragraph devoted by the HTML tag

.

Step 1: Extract the first paragraph

```
$srch_str = "<\p>";
$beginning_pos = strpos($article_content, $srch_str);
$beginning_text = substr($article_content, 0, $beginning_pos);
```

Step 2: Extract the rest of the text

```
$the_rest = substr($artcile_content, $beginning_pos + strlen($srch_str));
```

Step 3: Output

```
echo $beginning_text . <your ad code> . $the_rest;
```

The  section is the code you want inserted between the 2 pieces of article content. If the  section was large enough you may wish to redisplay the first paragraph at which point your output would be:

```
echo $beginning_text . <your ad code> . $beginning_text . $the_rest;
```

Comment: before we had it posting after the first paragraph, but now it's before. i'm trying to figure out what i can change back, but I  can't quite figure it out. 

It's also throwing random bits after the output...like a link fully code link without the opening < (href = .....) and other bits. The code itself is affecting surrounding areas is basically what I'm trying to say

Comment: The answer above should be identical to my previous comment if you change `$the_rest = substr($artcile_content, $beginning_pos + strlen($srch_str));` to `$the_rest = substr($artcile_content, $beginning_pos + 1);` That should get you back to where we were.

Comment: I've had weird things happen when attempting to use PHP to insert javascript into an HTML page. What I would guess for the link without the opening <a href= portion is that you define your PHP variable with a " instead of ' and use " in your href = HTML string. Therefore you have a " before the <a href= that isn't closed prior to the " for your link. Something like this maybe? `echo $beginning_text . "Blah, blah, <a href="http://mydomain.com">Great Site!</a>" . $the_rest;. The double quotes now interfere with each other.

Comment: It's just not working...I mean everything is great except for th random errors within the html. Caused by the ' and " I'd assume...I wonder if there is a more efficent way to get this done..The issue is that there is different outputs such as a href ect depending on the content from the database.

Comment: I find this sort of task to always be difficult to handle cleanly. If the data that you were trying to reformat had a very, very consistent format itself then there is typically some hook you can find that is good enough to be satisfactory. However, if the data is not heavily and very consistently formatted then I find you I am always stuck with more complicated logic. There are several approaches that could attempted but it all depends on specifically what you want vs the data. Typically the approaches involve format manipulation via PHP code first and then the insertion can be done easily.

Comment: The easiest way to code this would probably be to replace all the HTML tags except <p> and </p> with tokens - something like %%1%%. Keep an array of each HTML tag you replaced where the key is the full token string. Then add a token for the text/code your wish to insert after the first </p> in the text (assuming it is always present). It's important that you add a token not the actual text/code (any formatting issues like double quotes inside your insertion text may screw things up). Then do one str_replace with arrays and you are done.